# Write ` ' ` in Swift as text

Tags: ios, swift, text

I'd like to add text to a textField. The text includes a `'` and thats not accepted in Swift. Is there a way to say that this is text and not a symbol? For a `"` I write `\"` but this doesn't work.

Comment: `let string = "'hello'"` works fine for me, I don't know what's your problem

Comment: I get an error in my fetch request (`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: Unable to parse the format string "name = 'Yes, there's a way.'"

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your comment

> I get an error in my fetch request (`Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: Unable to parse the
>   format string "name = 'Yes, there's a way.'"

the *real* problem is that you used
string interpolation when creating a predicate for a fetch request.

```
let text = "'Yes, there's a way.'"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = \(text)")
```

crashes because all single and double quotes are special
characters in a predicate format string.

The correct way is to use var arg substitution:

```
let text = "'Yes, there's a way.'"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", text)
```

For more information, see [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) in the Predicate Programming Guide.

Comment: @user5473123: You have to show your code and input data, otherwise we cannot help.